# ASP.NET List Item IDs

Tags: asp.net, javascript, dom

The `<li>` tags generated by ASP.NET when I programatically add ListItems to my ListBox control do not have `ID` attributes.  Is there any way that I can get them to have `ID`s so that I can get references to the elements from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ListItem's attribute collection, like this...

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Attributes.Add("id", "myId");
myList.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I tried this, and the tags in the html still have no ID attribute.

Comment: Please post your code, when I run that exact snippet this is what I get for the html option being generated from the list item:


<option value="" id="myId"></option>

Comment: Sorry. It worked fine.  I had been looking in the wrong place.